# How can I change the images on an ImageButton in Android when using a OnTouchListener?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have the following code which creates an ImageButton and plays a sound when clicked:

```
ImageButton SoundButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sound1);
SoundButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_button);

SoundButton1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(1);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is that I want the image on the ImageButton to change when you press it. The OnTouchListener appears to be overriding the touch and not allowing the images to change. As soon as I remove the OnTouchListener, the ImageButton swaps to a different image when pressed. Any ideas on how I can have the images change on the ImageButton while still using the OnTouchListener? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution is simple: remove the `return true` from the ontouchlistener. Since that blocks all further operations that respond to touch and input. Make it `return false` too.

This way it will allow other actions to also respond to the touch.

Answer (score 35):

```
SoundButton1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(1);
            btnmode.setImageResource(R.drawable.modeitempressed);

        }
         elseif (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
            btnmode.setImageResource(R.drawable.modeitemnormal);

        }

        return false;
    }
});
```