# ImageButton android

Tags: android, image, button, imagebutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android ImageButton with a selected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state)

I was wondering whether there is a way to change the image of an ImageButton when it is clicked on? It is supposed to be a play/pause button so if the audio is playing then the image should be "pause" and once the user clicks pause the image should show "play"
thanks in advance

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2604599/190711 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/2716686/190711. Hope that helps.

Comment: You may refer this question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617969/how-can-i-change-the-images-on-an-imagebutton-in-android-when-using-a-ontouchlis][1] This has what you want.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617969/how-can-i-change-the-images-on-an-imagebutton-in-android-when-using-a-ontouchlis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds more of a [toggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) rather than a simple imageButton , since it has 2 states : playing , and paused/stopped .

Answer (score 0):

u can create method for pressed and also method for release.
in pressed method give image of oause, and in release method just give the image of play

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in this case :

Either Use **TOGGLE BUTTON**

or

Handle Clickable Event of your ImagButton i.e on its click change the Image Dynamically.Even you can have two buttons when

1. **When Play button is pressed :** Set Visibility of pause button **true** and for play Button Set visibility **gone**
2. **When Pause button is pressed :** Set Visibility of play button **true** and for pause Button Set visibility **gone**